# Expo build failed for Android on Prebuild

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Trying to build expo app with expo account using command 
`eas build --profile production --platform android` 
But from expo account, it fails at `Prebuild` with following error

```
[stderr] 
[21:33:34] Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
- Creating native project directories (./ios and ./android) and updating .gitignore
[stderr] 
[21:33:34] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/tmp/711fa9bbe006749d2a51950a7ec3922d/android'
- Creating native project directories (./ios and ./android) and updating .gitignore
✖ Failed to create the native project.
[21:33:34] You may want to delete the `./ios` and/or `./android` directories before trying again.
bash exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Since I am using `expo` and version `44.0.0`, I do not have android and ios folders.